# translation invariance of Lebesgue measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

How do you go about computing the translation invariance $\lambda_k(A)$ of some point **x** and a set *A*? Recall that $\lambda_k(A+x) = \lambda_k(A)$ for translation invariance given that for $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $A \in B^k$, we have $A+x=\{y | y=a+x,a\in A\}$ which is the translated version.  For instance, if we take a Lebesgue measure ($\mathbb{R}^2, B^2, \lambda_2$), a point $x = (2,3) \in \mathbb{R}$, and the set $A=\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2 \le 1\}$, what would $\lambda_2(A)$ look like?